# Onedrive OAuth 2.0 code flow for getting access token 'redirect uri' is not specified in the list of urls specified

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, onedrive

Before adding, yes it works when I give the entire url like http://localhost:8080/onedrive/oauth2/success/1 in the list of uri in azure uris. I am using code flow to authroize these tokens.
But as per the docs, it should work with me just mentioning the domain name there, like http://localhost:8080. Which it doesn't.

I want to do something like send the user id along with every request for me to keep track of which user I should link this accees token to, and have no idea to do so, if this issue is there. My current application logic is, when my application sends the user details and calls my spring API, I want to handle all these transfer of tokens in the server side, so I want to transfer this userId as my path variable. How do I go about doing this? Has anyone done this, can they explain to me any other different solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add custom details to OAuth redirects and it is best practice to always register the full redirect uri.

In terms of tracking the user, after login the token has a user id and you can also get fields such as user name and email - so both the UI and API will know which user each token is for. I can provide further details on mechanics if needed.

The user id in a token is often a generated value, whereas the user id you want to use in API path segments is maybe a user id from your app's back end database - if so you will need to map between token details and database details.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a possible idea, could you explain to me a bit more on how this works, I actually can see only token, expires_in, scope, refresh_token, token_type in the response, you mean when I can use the OAuth access token to get the email id? Also I am just trying to just have a Onedrive login to integrate into my existing system (my user could be xxx.company.com) and he could just integrate his onedrive from example xxx.outlook.com, not Sso. Could this be done? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah - ok - sounds like you want to get. a token for a user without authenticating or re-authenticating them. The access token won't contain anything about the user - is that right? Could you describe your current web app technology + login process for identifying users? Eg does it use logim cookies / is it a single page app? Feels like you should at least get a token from Azure that identifies this category of user so you can authorize requests in a controlled way.

Comment: Exactly, my current stack is spring boot+angular, it's still on Cookie-based csrf token basic authentication over http, over the time we might convert it with a authentication based on Oauth from our internal auth server, but we would still want this to connect to onedrive for content management. Thanks

Comment: The most standard option in this case is to leave user logins as they are and change the Spring web back end that calls the Spring API to use the [Client Credentials Flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/guides/client-credentials/call-api-client-credentials). This means the API receives a token that represents the web app's identity and not the end user identity. The end user id can be supplied to the API in a URL path segment as you've indicated - I assume you have this already. Only a single token is needed in your web back end and it will work for all users.

Comment: I could try this, is this applicable for personal accounts? I could try this if this works, could you point me towards any docs, I will try going through Microsoft docs to know more on how to implement this for now

Answer (score 0):

If you provide redirect uri as http://localhost:8080/ then it means you are handling the api response in

> /

endpoint and not

> /onedrive/oauth2/success/1

To get to know the user to whom you are linking, few ideas which you can use are

1) Use security to obtain the logged in user credentials (Ex: Principal if you're using Spring security in java)

2) After successful authentication, use the user id you have and send one more request to backend and store it database with userid as a key